# usb read from sensor

Tags: c#, usb, tilt-sensor

I have tilt sensor that have usb. How I read data from tilt sensor with usb in C#.

note : tilt sensor send data from usb connection.

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably access the tilt sensor using the HID interface.

There are lots of libraries you can use to access this library. So please search for "usb HID C#" on your favorite search engine.